# Show that the quadratic Gauss sum can be simplified by completing the square

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, gauss-sums

For natural numbers, $a,b,c$ the Gauss sum is defined as

$$G(a,b,c)=\sum_n^{c-1}e^{2\pi i\frac{an^2+bn}{c}}$$

From the [quadratic Gauss sum Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum) it is given that for odd $c$ and $\text{gcd}(a,c)=1$, one has

$${\displaystyle G(a,b,c)=\varepsilon _{c}{\sqrt {c}}\cdot \left({\frac {a}{c}}\right)e^{-2\pi i{\frac {\psi (a)b^{2}}{c}}}.}$$

where $\psi(a)$ is some number with $4\psi(a)a ≡ 1 \mod c$ and

$$\varepsilon_{m}=\begin{cases}1&\text{if}\ m\equiv 1\pmod 4,\\ i&\text{if}\ m\equiv 3\pmod 4\end{cases}$$

Note that for $b=0$ and odd $c$ it is given that

$$G(a,b=0,c)=\varepsilon_c\sqrt c \left(\frac a c\right)$$

so there is at least an implicit step which allows us to write

$${\displaystyle G(a,b,c)=G(a,0,c)e^{-2\pi i{\frac {\psi (a)b^{2}}{c}}}.}$$

But completing the square will result in a summation which looks like

$$G(a,b,c)=\sum_n^{c-1}e^{2\pi i\frac{a(n+b/2a)^2}{c}}e^{-2\pi i\frac{a(b/2a)^2}{c}}$$.

What is the missing step which allows us to ignore the $b/2a$ in the quadratic term?

Comment: summing over $n+x$ and summing over $n$ is the same thing

Comment: @tomos, this is what I guessed. the wiki article says "The Gauss sum G(a,b,c) depends only on the residue class of a and b modulo c" but is there some simple proof as to why? or do I need to go into number theory and understand residue classes etc?

Comment: you need to understand residue classes.

if you replace $n$ by $n+q$ in your gauss sum you can see that you're not changing anything.  so the only thing that matters is the \emph {residue} of $n$ modulo $q$.

Comment: sorry $c$ not $q$...

Comment: @tomos do you know of a self contained reference which could help me understand this? I am trying to read through chapter 3 of iwaniec and kowalski (analytic number theory) but it's going pretty slowly :D

Comment: off the top of my head, i would try Apostol's "An Introduction to Analytic Number Theory".  i would guess the iwaniec and kowlaski one is probably a bit too much atm